# how to connect Typeorm with msnodesqlv8 using nestjs window authentication

Tags: mysql, sql-server, nestjs, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to do window authentication using msnodesqlv8 in Nestjs. So, how to do this connection using TypeOrm?

```
const mypool = new mssql.ConnectionPool({
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  server: 'W70100\\SQLEXPRESS01',
  database: 'Test',
  port: 1433,
  options: {
  trustedConnection: true,
  useUTC: true
 },
});

const conn = mypool.connect().then(pool => {
 console.log('Connected to MSSQL (DB: mydb)', pool);
 var request = new mssql.Request(mypool);
  request.query('select * from [Test].[Emp]', (err, result) => {
  if (err) console.log('Database Connection Failed! ON RESULT: ',err);
  console.log(result)
 })
 // return pool;
}).catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))
```

This works well, but how to connect this connection string using Typeorm?TypeOrmModule.forRoot({})
Please advice.

Comment: Did you found solution?